# What happened to Delphi's ListView in FMX (.Detail and .Text are missing)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Some years ago, I used to use code like this:

```pascal
ShowMessage(lvDrinksListview.Items.Item[lvDrinksListview.ItemIndex].Text);
ShowMessage(lvDrinksListview.Items.Item[lvDrinksListview.ItemIndex].Detail);
```

I am now using Delphi 11 Community Edition, and this code reports errors:

```
[dcc64 Error] uMain.pas(652): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Detail'
[dcc64 Error] uMain.pas(651): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Text'
```

This is in an FMX app.

What is the replacement for `Detail` and `Text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [big refactoring of `TListView` in Delphi 10.0 Seattle](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Refactoring_of_the_List_View_Control_in_Seattle). Your old code predates that release.

The `Item[]` property now returns a base [`TListItem`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.Types.TListItem) class, which does not have the `Detail` or `Text` properties that you are looking for, hence the errors.

To resolve this, you can simply type-cast each Item to [`TListViewItem`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.Appearances.TListViewItem), which derives from `TListItem` and does have the properties you want, eg:

```
ShowMessage(TListViewItem(lvDrinksListview.Items[lvDrinksListview.ItemIndex]).Text);
ShowMessage(TListItemItem(lvDrinksListview.Items[lvDrinksListview.ItemIndex]).Detail);
```

I would suggest you use a local variable to clean that up a bit:

```
var Item := TListViewItem(lvDrinksListview.Items[lvDrinksListview.ItemIndex]);
ShowMessage(Item.Text);
ShowMessage(Item.Detail);
```